# Get GPO information using Microsoft.GroupPolicy

Tags: c#, gpo

We're trying to get the information of GPOs of our computers. Therefore we want to use c# - and not gpresult.exe (because it can be executed in system context...).

Well, as I found out there's a DLL Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Management.dll that can be imported in C#. It sounded too easy:

```
using Microsoft.GroupPolicy;

[...]

GPRsop rsop = new GPRsop(RsopMode.Logging, "root\\RSOP\\Computer");
rsop.LoggingComputer = "MyComputer";
rsop.LoggingUser = "domain\\user";
rsop.LoggingMode = LoggingMode.Computer;
rsop.CreateQueryResults();
rsop.GenerateReportToFile(ReportType.Xml, "C:\\Temp\\test.xml");
```

As output file I get this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Rsop xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Rsop">
  <ReadTime>2013-05-06T13:28:17.1529206Z</ReadTime>
  <DataType>LoggedData</DataType>
</Rsop>
```

Anyone here who ever worked with this DLL and can give me some hints?
Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should execute `rsop.CreateQueryResults()`, before you generate the report. This requires the `LoggingMode`, `LoggingUser` and `LoggingComputer` properties to be set.

Comment: Sound good, but whenever I want to set `LoggingMode`, `LoggingUser` or `LoggingComputer` I get an "out of range" exception with "Argument Exception Was Unhandled".

Comment: No problem. Which line throws the exception? Have you tried them individually to see if they all fail or just one? I only have 15 mins left before I leave home, but I can check later when I return if you can give me that information.

Comment: All lines fail: 
`rsop.LoggingComputer = "MyComputer";
rsop.LoggingUser = "domain\\user";
rsop.LoggingMode = LoggingMode.Computer;
rsop.CreateQueryResults();`

Answer (score 0):

```cs
GPRsop rsop = new GPRsop(RsopMode.Logging, null);
rsop.LoggingMode = LoggingMode.Computer;
rsop.LoggingComputer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME");
rsop.LoggingUser = Environment.UserDomainName + @"\" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME");

rsop.CreateQueryResults();
var xml = rsop.GenerateReport(ReportType.Xml);
```

GPMGMTLib used

```cs
GPM gpm = new GPM();
var rsop = gpm.GetRSOP(GPMRSOPMode.rsopLogging, null, 0);
rsop.LoggingFlags = 0x20000;
rsop.LoggingComputer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME");
rsop.LoggingUser = Environment.UserDomainName + @"\" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME");
rsop.CreateQueryResults();

object cancel = new GPMAsyncCancel();
var result = rsop.GenerateReport(GPMReportType.repXML, null, out cancel);
string xml = result.Result;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
        using GPMGMTLib;


        GPM groupPolicyManagement = new GPM();
        IGPMConstants groupPolicyConstants = groupPolicyManagement.GetConstants();
        GPMRSOP rsop = groupPolicyManagement.GetRSOP(groupPolicyConstants.RSOPModeLogging, null, 0);
        rsop.LoggingComputer = "MyComputer";
        rsop.LoggingUser = "domain\\user";
        rsop.CreateQueryResults();
        rsop.GenerateReportToFile(groupPolicyConstants.ReportXML, "C:\\Temp\\test.xml");
```