# C# gpresult /r equivalent

Tags: c#, group-policy

I'm writing a small app that checks to see if a computer and current user are members of the appropriate security groups in Active Directory. I stumbled across this question [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399934/get-gpo-information-using-microsoft-grouppolicy) but it looks like it was forgotten and I'm running into the same issues as the OP. The end result is I want to be able to create an array that is very similar to running the following command from a command prompt.

```
gpresult /r
```

Here is a code sample that I have tried from the above link, I'm running into the same errors as the OP specifically "out of range" exception" when attempting to set LoggingUser and LoggingComputer. Since I can't get past these errors I'm not even sure if this method is the right route.

```
GPRsop rsop = new GPRsop(RsopMode.Logging, "root\\RSOP\\Computer");
rsop.LoggingComputer = "MyComputer";
rsop.LoggingUser = "domain\\user";
rsop.LoggingMode = LoggingMode.Computer;
rsop.CreateQueryResults();
rsop.GenerateReportToFile(ReportType.Xml, "C:\\Temp\\test.xml");
```

Comment: Did you research this question before asking it on Stack Overflow? I can understand exactly what it is you want, but have you tried any code beforehand?

Comment: Yes as I said above I found a similar question and tried the proposed answers but ran into the same issues as the OP.

Comment: Please could you post the code that you have tried (don't post it in the comments, edit your question and add it in there)?

Comment: Code has been updated, thanks for your help btw.

Comment: is this the code you are running word for word, in production? because this code would require you to replace those magic strings with appropriate values for your environment.  I'm sure you aren't running the program as "user" from the "domain" domain on "MyComputer"....

Comment: No I pulled out the actual computername and domain\\user. It doesn't matter what I set the strings to real values or not I get the same error.

Comment: @AndrewCounts, do you expect OP will provide internal company data to ask a question on SO?

Comment: is this code being run with administrative rights?

Comment: Yes I've tried from domain and local admin accounts.

Comment: specifically, I was meaning right clicking the app, run as administrator.

Comment: The problem is I cannot even compile the code because of the exception errors when attempting to set rsop.LoggingComputer = "MyComputer";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a roundabout way to accomplish what I needed by reading the registry keys located in "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\History" for applied group policies, added them to an ArrayList then checked to see if the list contained the policy I'm interested in.

To make sure these keys are dynamically updated, I removed the machine in question from the GPO group, rebooted and the keys associated with that policy were removed.

```
            ArrayList groupPolicies = new ArrayList();

        using (RegistryKey historyKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\History"))
        {
            foreach (string historySubkey in historyKey.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                using (RegistryKey guidKey = historyKey.OpenSubKey(historySubkey))
                {
                    foreach (string guidsubkey in guidKey.GetSubKeyNames())
                    {
                        using (RegistryKey keyvalue = guidKey.OpenSubKey(guidsubkey))
                        {
                            groupPolicies.Add(keyvalue.GetValue("DisplayName"));
                            //Console.WriteLine(keyvalue.GetValue("DisplayName"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (!groupPolicies.Contains("replacewithyourGPOname"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The machine is not a member of the policy");
        }
```